# Grab image type from SQL and display in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sql-server, image

I have SharePoint Foundation 2013.  I have employee information (name, titles, dates, photo [image type]) in a SQL database.  I want to be able to grab this employee data from the SQL table and display them in a slideshow/slider type thing in SharePoint.  I'm not sure how to do that at all.  I know BCS doesn't allow the complex type of image so I'm at a loss as to how to get and read the images in SharePoint and then display them, along with the other information for each employee.

Comment: Is the image field a SQL blob or is it just a reference to an image stored on a network location?

Comment: The image is stored in SQL as an image type (not a reference to an image stored on the network)